# ubuntu install specific nvidia drivers command line

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, ubuntu-11.04

In short only a specific driver works for my current step up.

I know I can install current drivers with

```
Sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

But how would I install say version 2.91?

Comment: Try searching for it to see if it's in the repositories. `aptitude search nvidia | grep "2.91"` or variants of that.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can't find the answer to one of your questions on Super User, other StackExchange sites might have it. Check it out here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version.